# What causes nullpointerexception: caused by code or not?

Tags: android

I installed Acra so I sometimes receive error logs from devices where my app crashes. 
I solved some of them, but there **remain 4 kind of nullpointerexceptions** which I seem not to be able to track what causes them.. Is it my code or something else? Can't seem to figure it out.

These never happen on my own device, but on others which I receive through the reporting...

```
//ERROR 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.game/com.package.game.Answer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.package.game.Answer.onCreate(Answer.java:93)
//line 93 = font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.package.game.Answer.onCreate(Answer.java:93)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

// ERROR 2
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
at com.package.game.Answer.mark(Answer.java:430)
// 430 = Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

at com.package.game.Answer.onClick(Answer.java:389)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2391)
at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4206)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3736)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:855)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:887)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:887)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:887)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:887)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1662)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1110)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1646)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1708)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

//ERROR 3
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.didFirstLayout(WebViewCore.java:1617)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.nativeStopLoading(Native Method)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stopLoading(BrowserFrame.java:778)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.stopLoading(WebViewCore.java:1119)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:728)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:471)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)


//ERROR 4

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.package.game.CustomArrayAdapter.getView(CustomArrayAdapter.java:75)
//75 = int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();

at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1435)
at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1222)
at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:268)
at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:221)
at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:340)
at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1114)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1265)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7212)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7212)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7212)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7212)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try this in your Error:1 Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(myContext.getAssets(), "FONT.TTF");

Comment: I'll try that.. don't know for sure if that is the cause, my other activities are using the same font and don't cause errors... it that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the String variables and then check the code again for values...

```
String xyz="";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.. :) Which String variables?

Comment: Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

    Calling the instance method of a null object.
    Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
    Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
    Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should also include Answer.java and let's see what's wrong with it. And sometimes, what the logs say about which line the application went wrong is inaccurate. The error could be in Line 93 or it could be in Line 92. Please do post your code. It would greatly help.